# What is a more efficient way of extracting a value from a webpage

Tags: .net, performance, web-scraping

I need to retrieve a value from a website (can vary and I have no control over the site). I currently have some code that works... but takes a very long time to run. I know that there is a vastly improved way of doing this, I just don't know what that is.

I have considered several alternatives like Regex and the HTMLAgilityPack (seems complex and possibly overkill?) but without trying each of them I am not sure what would be most efficient. And I am sure there are many more possibilities as well.

The problem may even be with how I am retrieving the page rather than how I am processing it.

```
    Dim GETURL As WebRequest
    GETURL = WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com")
    Dim objStream As Stream = GETURL.GetResponse.GetResponseStream()

    Dim objReader As New StreamReader(objStream)
    Dim sLine As String = ""
    Dim a As Integer = 0
    Dim result As String = ""
    Do While Not sLine Is Nothing
        a += 1
        sLine = objReader.ReadLine
        If Not sLine Is Nothing Then
            result += sLine
        End If
    Loop

    Dim startTag as string ="<some html tag>"
    Dim endTag as string ="<closing tag>"
    Dim firstIndex As Integer = result.IndexOf(startTag) + startTag.Length
    result = result.Substring(firstIndex, result.Length - firstIndex)
    Dim RequiredVal As String = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf(endTag))
```

Please note, I do realise just how hideously inefficient this code is, but rather than try loads of different permutations (and probably still have fairly inefficient code), I thought I would ask some experts for their advice first :-)

**UPDATE:**

As I didn't get any response (perhaps my question was a little too vague?) I have been trying to improve efficiency on my own. I have managed to decrease the time it takes to run by ~50% by using WebCient.DownloadString(). This is good but I suspect I can make improvements on extracting the data from the page. Please see updated code below:

```
    Dim client As New WebClient()
    Dim result As String = client.DownloadString("http://www.example.com")

    Dim startTag as string ="<some html tag>"
    Dim endTag as string ="<closing tag>"
    Dim firstIndex As Integer = result.IndexOf(startTag) + startTag.Length
    result = result.Substring(firstIndex, result.Length - firstIndex)
    Dim RequiredVal As String = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf(endTag))
```

Any Suggestions would be greatly apprieciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is with waiting for the response from the web request, then the actual engine or technique you use to parse it probably has a lot less to do with performance, than simply waiting for each response from the web synchronously. If you have a long list of pages you're scraping, then you can do better by running simultaneous requests asynchronously. It's not clear that's what is going on though.

Try [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) - also on [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery) - a new C# port of jQuery which should do what you want. It has methods for grabbing data synchronously and asynchronously, so if you did want to start parallel web requests, it can do that out of the box. At the most basic level though, the code would be this to do it synchronously:

```
CQ doc = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://www.jquery.com");

string allStuffInsideTag = doc["sometag"].Contents().RenderSelection();
```

It works like jquery. The "CQ" object is the same as a jQuery object. `Contents` is the jQuery method to return all children of an element; `RenderSelection` is a CsQuery method that renders the full HTML of every element in the selection set.  So this would return the full text & html of everything inside every `sometag` block.

Also it indexes each document for all common selector types and is much faster than HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: Thank you. TBH I am not sure if the problem is with waiting for the response or with the processing. Now, you mention it though, it is much more likely to be the requests that are taking the time. I don't have a long list (at least when time is an issue). There will be a max of 10 requests. Doing the requests async might be an option, although it may get a bit messy as I would need them all to return a value before moving on. The CsQuery certainly looks like an elegant solution and impressive if it is faster than Agility as you say.

Comment: It should not be too hard to manage waiting for all the async callbacks. In C#5 you can use `Tasks.WaitAll`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx .. personally I'm still using VS2010, so I did implement something similar in CsQuery, see When.All under: https://github.com/jamietre/csquery#promises CsQuery is much faster than HAP for selectors, actually I just ran some numbers: http://blog.outsharked.com/2012/06/csquery-performance-vs-fizzler.html  but again - depending on what you're extracting and the size of the pages -- you could just be waiting for the server.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, not been on for a while cos of trying to sort some car trouble. I Think I am probably gonna request and process the one time critical page, then process the rest after sending a response to the user. I will then see what the response time is like and will keep your suggestions in mind if I need to do further optimising (which I will do at some point). Many of your suggestions will also be very helpful in other projects, so thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WatiN](http://watin.org) or better the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com).

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I have not seen WatiN before, I don't think its well suited to the particular problem but it does look interesting for another project. I agree the HTML Agility Pack is a possibility. I am just concerned that adding a whole library like that would be overkill for this one little function. Before I learn how to use it, is it likely to be a big improvement?